# Enforce first hash and array element to be on the same line in rubocop

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I'm looking for a way to enforce this way of writing hashes and arrays using rubocop:

```
a = { first: 'a',
      second: 'b' }
```

I found rules to enforce closing brace and indentation. But can't enforce the first element to be inline with an opening brace. Is it possible?

So far I found `Style/FirstHashElementLineBreak`, but it does the opposite.

To force the closing brace to be on the same line as the last key I use this:

```
Style/MultilineHashBraceLayout:
  EnforcedStyle: same_line
```

But this setting kind of not make sense without forcing the opening brace to be on the same line as the first key.

I'm asking people who ever tried to do similar thing, or who have a good knowledge of rubocop's configuration, is it possible to do so, and if it is, how to do it?

Comment: Normally we put everything on one line for short hashes, or break into multiple lines with the braces on separate lines. Rubocop does things a specific way to match the coding guidelines for the Ruby community. Changing it will break that compatibility. I'd recommend getting used to writing code that meets the guidelines otherwise you'll find that code-reviews can be quite embarrassing.

Comment: Rubocop is configurable to enforce different possible rule sets. Different companies develop their own styles that better fit their environment. I found many different configurations in the internet from companies like GitHub and ThoughtBot. I'm looking for a way to configure it to use coding style accepted in my company, and this style is unlikely to be changed.

Comment: That's true. Companies are different, though even in ours we accepted the regular forms since we use, and create, open-source. The Stack Overflow way to ask a question like yours, is to show what you tried, and explain why it didn't work. That helps narrow the question and speeds up answering. See "[ask]" and its linked pages, and "[mcve]".

Comment: I think the question is simple enough: is it possible to enforce the style that I put in the example. I also wrote what did I try and what I couldn't find. Rubocop documentation is huge and is missing some features that are actually implemented. So I'm asking people who ever tried to do similar thing, or who have a good knowledge of rubocop's configuration, is it possible to do so, and if it is, how to do it.

Comment: "Rubocop does things a specific way to match the coding guidelines for the Ruby community."

While this used to be true, it is no longer the case. RuboCop now aspires to complete configurability to allow people to enforce their company guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the `Style/MultilineHashBraceLayout` has been renamed `Layout/MultilineHashBraceLayout` and second the default config for it now `symmetrical` does exactly what you want.

[From the docs](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/manual/cops_layout.md):

> When using the symmetrical (default) style:
>
> If a hash's opening brace is on the same line as the first element of
>   the hash, then the closing brace should be on the same line as the
>   last element of the hash.
>
> If a hash's opening brace is on the line above the first element of
>   the hash, then the closing brace should be on the line below the last
>   element of the hash.

So running `rubocop --only Layout/MultilineHashBraceLayout` on the code above will yield now offenses.